# ncorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView

Tags: android

When I run my android app in android studio, I get the below error and the app is hanging. Please advise.

```
    04/04 14:52:49: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/dep/dependencies.apk /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_0.apk /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_1.apk /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_3.apk /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_8.apk /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_2.apk /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_9.apk /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_4.apk /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_7.apk /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_6.apk /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_5.apk /Users/shakeralmoosa/Documents/RemoteData/MySqlDemo/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.shakeralmoosa.mysqldemo/com.example.shakeralmoosa.mysqldemo.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 11347 on device emulator-5554
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.shakeralmoosa.mysqldemo-2/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9873e540: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9873e540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9877e7b0)
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9873e540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9877e7b0)
```

Comment: Turn OFF `Instant Run` and then after `clean` and `Rebuild`

Comment: @NikunjParadva the issue disappear.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog: On Windows or Linux, select `File > Settings` from the menu bar. On Mac OSX, select `Android Studio > Preferences` from the menu bar.
2. Navigate to `Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run`.
3. Uncheck the box next to `Restart activity on code changes`.
4. Choose `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...`
5. `Rebuild` your project